# Is there a way to dynamically extend the free trial period of a Shopify App?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have my app in production working great! Now a feature that I would like to add is to extend a user's free trial period depending on if they take a specific action. Is there a way to do this manually? How about programmatically? Thanks, Lucas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to modify a charge but you have two options (both through the API):

- If the trial has not ended then you could create another charge with a new trial period and ask the merchant to accept that. Once the new charge is activated it will replace the old charge.
- If the trial ended then you could [give the merchant an application credit](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/applicationcredit#create) in lieu of a longer trial.

Comment: I ended up having my code create a new charge and it's working great

Comment: Glad to hear it 